# Python: how to unpack variable-length data from byte string?

Tags: python, unpack

There's a byte-string like this:

```
[lenght1][sequence1][len2][seq2][len3][seq3][len1][seq1]...
```

where `lengthX` is the length of the `sequenceX` following just after that `lenghtX`. Please note there're no separators at all, and all "len-data" pairs are grouped in a set of three (after `seq3` immediately comes `len1` of the next group).

I'm trying to extract all sequences, but looks like using `struct.unpack()` is very cumbersome (or idk how to use it properly):

```
 loop_start:
   my_len = unpack("<B", content[:1])[0]
   content = content[1:]
   ..get sequence1
   ..shift byte-string
   ..repeat two times...
```

Is there any simpler way?

p.s. seqX is in fact multi-byte string, if it's matter.

Comment: If the length data is of a persistent type (e.g. `int`, therefore 4 byte), you can use `struct.unpack` at least for that part. For a variable length, as your data is, you would have to make some kind of lookup table (e.g. `length == 4: I`) to use with `struct`as well. On the other hand, you can just always use`long long` (8 bytes) and remove padding according to the `length`.

Comment: @white could you please explain that part `length == 4: I` ? I don't understand it at all except 4 is the int size.

Comment: struct.unpack is the correct technology. However, you will need to know what format was used to pack the data in the first place. Take a look here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html Not sure what you mean by "groups of three". Looks more like groups of two - i.e., length/data. If you could provide some sample data we'll be able to advise further

Comment: I was talking about how the `struct.unpack` function is defined: You need to give a format string for the corresponding C-types. `I` is for unsigned integer. You can lookup the format/types here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters

Comment: @DarkKnight format - I can play with "s" or "c" (in fact it's multi-byte string), set of three means after `seq3` immediately comes `len1` of the next group

Comment: @white and the problem is idk how to create dynamic format. Assuming seqX can be unpacked using `c*len1`, how can it be done in one `unpack`, not in two?

Comment: @Putnik: where's the problem with using 2 `unpack` calls?

Comment: @SergeBallesta if it can be done in one, instead of two then I'll be able to do it in one instead of six and extract three pairs at one time.

Comment: If your format type is c (C-type char) then you're going to be very limited in terms of your data lengths. Are you sure that's what you have/want. Please provide sample data and expected output

Comment: @Putnik AFAIK it is not possible with the standard library `struct` module. If you want it to appear as a single call, you can wrap it in a Python function. If you can prove (by profiling) that you really need better performance, and are using CPython, you can write a C extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This data structure is very useful when, for example, sending arbitrary data over a socket. Using separators can be problematic due to ambiguity - e.g, if you use STX/ETX there may be an issue if the [real] data contains the equivalent of either of those markers.

Sending data with length/data pairs removes ambiguity. All that needs to happen is that the client and server need to agree on the format of the length value being transmitted (native, little- big-endian).

This is best explained by example.

We have a list of strings and we build a bytearray of length/data pairs. We'll agree on native unsigned int for the preamble. We know that the packed value is comprised of 4 bytes.

So...

```
from struct import pack, unpack

strings = [
    'To be, or not to be: that is the question',
    'All the world\'s a stage, and all the men and women merely players',
    'We are such stuff as dreams are made on',
    'The course of true love never did run smooth',
    'If music be the food of love, play on',
    'Friends, Romans, countrymen, lend me your ears',
    'A horse! a horse! my kingdom for a horse!',
    'Once more unto the breach, dear friends, once more',
    'To thine own self be true',
    'Parting is such sweet sorrow'
]

FMT = '=I' # native unsigned int
FMTL = 4 # standard size

b = bytearray()

for string in strings:
    bs = string.encode()
    b += pack(FMT, len(bs)) + bs

# at this point we have a bytearray comprised of length/data pairs
# now let's unravel it

while b:
    length, *_ = unpack(FMT, b[:FMTL])
    print(b[FMTL:length+FMTL].decode())
    b = b[length+FMTL:]
```

This code is easily adapted for any integer type by specifying FMT and FMTL appropriately. Type 'c' is hinted at in OP's question. That has to be dealt with in a slightly different manner

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no example how the data could look like, I provided my own sample (`length` is always a integer, therefore 4 bytes). If your bytes come in big- or little endian you have to see for yourself. I decided to use big endian since it's a bit easier to read an understand. To change that, you just have to change the `>` to `<`.
The code works by padding the number and using the biggest available type (`unsigned long long`). Since added zeroes on the left side of a big endian number does not have any effect, this approach should work. For little endian, you have to add the `padding` to the right side.
To prevent problems with different architectures, where data types may differ, the size of the needed padding is calculated using `struct.calcsize()`.

```py
import struct


content = b'\x00\x00\x00\x04\x12\x4a\x13\x10\x00\x00\x00\x03\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff'
out = []

while True:
    if content == b'':
        break
    length = struct.unpack('>I', content[:4])[0]
    pad_len = struct.calcsize('Q') - length
    padding = b'\x00' * pad_len
    value = struct.unpack('>Q', padding + content[4:4+length])[0]
    out.append(value)
    content = content[4+length:]

print(out)
```

output:

```
[306844432, 65537, 255]
```